# JQuery Autocomplete suggestions inside suggestions

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have made jQuery Autocomplete. It shows the suggestions also. I now want the suggestion shows sub suggestions when mouse is hovered on it . how??

Answer (score 0):

Use `autocomplete="off"` on the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Simply open terminal, type 
`npm install @types/jquery --save`
Press enter and you are done.